# How to change the layout of a Tkinter Combobox?

Tags: python, tkinter

To make the border disapear or simply change it's color. I tried with highlighttickness or borderwidth but it doesn't work. So I was told to try with the layouts, the thing is I don't know how to change the border with the layouts

On this pic the border is still visible on the combobox I want to delete it or just change it's color

PS : That's not a duplicate previous questions were deleted

[image: test]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the layout with the `layout` method of a style object. It can take as an argument a new layout to replace the current layout.

The following example illustrates how to remove the padding element around the checkbox, which I think might be the source of your light gray border:

```
style = ttk.Style()
layout = [
    ('Combobox.button', {
        'sticky': 'nswe',
        'children': [
                    ('Combobox.textarea', {
                        'sticky': 'nswe'
                    })
                ]
            })
]
style.layout("TCombobox", layout)
```

Changing styles and style layouts is unfortunately an under-documented feature of tkinter. However, there are several resources on the internet you might find useful:

- [tkinter.ttk.Style.layout](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.ttk.html#tkinter.ttk.Style.layout) from the official python documentation
- [What's inside a style](https://tkdocs.com/tutorial/styles.html#insidestyle) on tkdocs.com
- [Ttk Elements](https://www.pythontutorial.net/tkinter/ttk-elements/) on pythontutorial.net
- [ttk layouts: structuring a style](https://anzeljg.github.io/rin2/book2/2405/docs/tkinter/ttk-layouts.html) from New Mexico Tech Tk 8.5 reference (archive copy)

Comment: Thank you very much ! I'll also check the links, but one last thing why the "changer" is gone ?  idk how it's called but know my combobox kinda look entry now haha. Thanks anyway